# FFmpeg library in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I am building a softwere that can decode and encode using Wpf and c#, and I want to do that using, FFmpeg libary. I saw the ffmpeg autogen warpper but I couldn't find any documantion for its function.
Can someone please find me one? Or better, give me better warrper.

I already tried FFMpegCore, its working but very slow. For Exaple it takes 20 seconds to decode a specific frame.(And i have monstruos computer)
If will be happy if ou could give me better warpper, or a guide for ffmpeg.autogen.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FFMPEG autogen is great but it's like coding in c with lot of pointers. You must use the ffmpeg documentation as is. From my quick experience, ffmpeg.exe contains lot of polish that you will need to re-implement if using ffmpeg autogen

Comment: @Kalten So what do you offer me to do?

Comment: Not much. Start with [autogen sample](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/tree/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example), then [ffmpeg c sample](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html). And be prepare to long nights :p

Comment: @Kalten is there other way to communicate with ffmpeg.exe directly, without autogen? And thanks for the help!

Comment: The other way I know is to call ffmpeg.exe with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...)` but it's what FFMpegCore do. And as you notice, it's way more slower. What I could suggest is to try an other lib than ffmpeg. Maybe vlc => https://www.nuget.org/profiles/videolan https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp

Comment: @Kalten can you crop and trim in this libary?

Comment: You can, but it's not straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg framework is powerful, from the other hand is so large which makes it complex. If you want to mess with it, you will have to read a lot before start coding. I would recommend starting with the original documentation and examples that can be found here :-

- [FFmpeg Libraries Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html#libraries)
- [FFmpeg C Examples](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html)

And then move to some open source examples -based on what you want- coded in C# with FFmpeg.Autogen bindings.

You can check my recent FFmpeg.cs implementation that is for decoding (audio/video/subtitle frames).

- [FFmpeg.Autogen C# Example](https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf/blob/master/Flyleaf/MediaDecoder.cs)

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've been building my own media player to cater for my needs and I'm using
Flyleaf:https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf which is based on FFMPEG. There are samples in the code to get you started.

I've also seen this: FFME: https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement